# How to unit test the (de)serialization of a custom exception without BinaryFormatter?

Tags: c#, .net, serialization

There are a lot of StackOverflow answers explaining how to write a unit test for a custom exception class.

But all of them use the class BinaryFormatter to serialize and deserialize. [Problem: It is suggested, not to use it anymore](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/syslib-diagnostics/syslib0011).

But how to do it then?

This is the code so far (with BinarFormatter):

```cs
        [TestMethod]
        public void test()
        {
            // Arrange
            const string TestMessage = "testMessage";
            var exception = new AbcException(TestMessage);
            using var stream = new MemoryStream();
            var formatter = new BinaryFormatter();

            // Act
            formatter.Serialize(stream, exception);
            stream.Position = 0; // Reset stream position

            var deserializedException = (AbcException)formatter.Deserialize(stream);

            // Assert
            Assert.AreEqual(TestMessage, deserializedException.Message);
        }
```

Comment: `all of them use the class BinaryFormatter to serialize and deserialize` can you post a link? I've never seen a unit test that requires serialization to test exceptions. Your code certainly doesn't need it. You can use `Assert.AreEqual(testMessage,exception.Message);` You'd only have to use serialization if you actually customized the serialization constructor and wanted to test it.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Exceptions need to support serialization so that they can be thrown across AppDomain boundaries. It seems therefore reasonable to also test the serialization code if AppDomains are to be supported (so not in .NET Core or .NET 6).

Comment: If you customized exception serialization then any serializer will work, including XmlSerializer. Typically, exception serialization was added to allow serializing exceptions in web (SOAP) services. Which wasn't a great idea. Almost all custom exceptions just call the base constructor so don't have to be tested.

Comment: @KlausGütter they need to be tested only if they use custom serialization code. Otherwise the test is exercising `System.Exception(info,context)`.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the recommendations originate with [.Net remoting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Remoting), i.e. if a remote call produces an exception it needs to be serialized to transfer to the client.

.Net remoting is fairly rare in modern development that usually use REST or some other more modern protocol for client-server communication, and these usually have some other way to report errors, like http status codes.

So in practice I see little need to write unit tests to test serialization of exceptions unless you actually use .Net remoting or any other binaryFormatter-based technology. And if you do, you might think about migrating to newer technologies.

So my recommendations would be to just not write any such tests. And in general, if you don't know why you are writing a unit test, don't. Or at least, try to find out why such recommendations exist before following them.

Comment: I think, the confusion came from the fact that our company has a code template for exceptions that generates them with the Serializable attribute. And as soon as that is in there, there is a warning (CA2229) if you don't implement the serialization methods. So, I implemented it and because I had no idea whether I implemented it correctly, I wrote a unit test.

Comment: After I removed the Serializable attribute, our SonarQube complained about that: "Classes which inherit from Exception are implementing ISerializable. Make sure [Serializable] attribute is used and that ISerializable is correctly implemented. Even it you don’t plan to explicitly serialize the object yourself, it might still require serialization, for instance when crossing the boundary of an AppDomain."

Comment: @ndsvw Using multiple appdomains is also a rather niche usage. Note that ISerializable attribute might be used by other serialization libraries, not just BinaryFormatter. So you need to decide if you want to support serializable exceptions, and if so, using what serialization, or disable the warning.